# how to fix ErrorException Undefined property App\Controllers\User::$form_validation in CI4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I got an error trying to function edit

[I got an error trying to function edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWH6H.png)

to be honest I'm confused about placing the form validation library in codeigniter 4. can you guys help me?

edit_profile.php

```
public function edit_profile()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';

        // $users = new \Myth\Auth\Models\UserModel();
        // $data['users'] = $users->findAll();

        $this->form_validation->setRule('username', 'Username', 'required|trim');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $this->builder->select('users.id as userid, username, fullname, user_image, email, name');
            $this->builder->join('auth_groups_users', 'auth_groups_users.user_id = users.id');
            $this->builder->join('auth_groups', 'auth_groups.id = auth_groups_users.group_id');
            $this->query = $this->builder->get();

            $data['users'] = $this->query->getResult();
        }
        return view('user/edit_profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post links to images of code or errors. Include the relevant text inside the body of your question using the appropriate formatting tags instead. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where are you loading the `Validation` Library? Where is `form_validation` coming from? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html#loading-the-library